# asterisk originate drops calls

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami

I am using asterisk(1.6.2.13) to mass originate to specified numbers that are come from mysql database using perl and AMI.
if I send all calls (simultaneous) to asterisk, it will drop half of them after about 20 seconds. but if I sleep for 1 second between each originate it will process the call clearly. so this will reduce the capacity of origination.

Is there any way to  get rid of this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk uses a single thread to process all SIP messages, and everything relating to SIP messaging happens in this thread (eg. realtime database access). This imposes an upper limit on the number of calls that can be processed per second. You can monitor the unprocessed SIP packets on the socket queue using something like "netstat -na |grep 5060". I've found it can up to 200 call setups per second, beyond that it will start losing and retransmitting packets and eventually dropping calls.